# How to make Vector CANOE recognise the STM8 board connected via the interface?

Tags: can-bus, canoe, stm8

I tried to program the STM8 board to send CAN messages which can be viewed with the help of Vector CANoe. However the messages are in pending state and I am not able to make the Vector CANoe recognise the stm8 board connected via the hardware interface. How can I send view the messages that are sent by the microcontroller board in the CANoe trace window?
Thanks.

Comment: You might mention which can controller (builtin? which chip?) you're using. It might also be easier to start with two identical boards trying to talk CAN to each other before trying to get different nodes going.